# How to prove commutative property for rational number in Agda?

Tags: agda

I am trying to prove commutative property for agda. I tried to explore the standard library but there is lot of complex thing which i could not understand.
I tried in this way --

```
comm : (a b : Q) -> (a + b) === (b + a)
```

the problem here is + which is not defined over Q in library. Can't we proof this without defining + over Q.
Please guide me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add two rational in agda?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212459/how-to-add-two-rational-in-agda)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prove this without first defining *+*.

If you get confused exploring the standard library I suggest you try to prove something easier first, in order to become more acquainted with Agda, before tackling this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't prove commutativity of an undefined function `_+_`; as a stupid counter-example, would you expect to be able to prove `(a - b) == (b - a)`? If not, why not? `_-_` is just as much of an undefined function as `_+_` at this point; it just has a different name...

Note that you can define addition for `ℚ` using elementary school math:

```
n ÷ p + m ÷ q = (n * q + m * p) ÷ (p * q)
```

and simplifying it by dividing both `n * q + m * p` and `p * q` with their GCD. I have already explained the details of this last step in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31265445/477476).